# Snowflake:Export data in multiple delimiter format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Requirement:**

Need the file to be exported as below format, where gender, age, and interest are columns and value after `:` is data for that column. Can this be achieved while using Snowflake, if not is it possible to export data using Python

```
User1234^gender:male;age:18-24;interest:fishing
User2345^gender:female
User3456^age:35-44
User4567^gender:male;interest:fishing,boating
```

> EDIT 1: Solution as given by @demircioglu

It displays as NULL values instead of other column values

Below the EMPLOYEES table data

[image]

When I ran below query

```
SELECT 'EMP_ID'||EMP_ID||'^'||'FIRST_NAME'||':'||FIRST_NAME||';'||'LAST_NAME'||':'||LAST_NAME FROM tempdw.EMPLOYEES  ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your SQL with the desired format and write it to a file

```
COPY INTO @~/stage_data
FROM 
(
SELECT 'User'||User||'^'||'gender'||':'||gender||';'||'age'||':'||age||';'||'interest'||':'||interest FROM table
)
file_format = (TYPE=CSV compression='gzip')
```

File format here is not important because each line will be treated as a field because of your delimiter requirements

Edit:
`CONCAT` function (aliased with `||`) returns NULL if you have a NULL value.
In order to eliminate NULLs you can use [NVL2](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl2.html#nvl2) function

So your SQL will have series of `NVL2`s

NVL2 checks the first parameter and if it's not NULL returns first expression, if it's NULL returns second expression

So for User column

`'User'||User||'^'` will turn into

```
NVL2(User,'User','')||NVL2(User,User,'')||NVL2(User,'^','')
```

P.S. I am leaving up to you to create the rest of the SQL, because Stackoverflow's function is to help find the solution, not spoon feed the solution.

Comment: If for example for some row if no data for particular column say age and  interest , it has to output as `User2345^gender:female`

Comment: Please check the updated original question i have ran the query with your solution  but gives NULL

Comment: Updated the answer to eliminate NULLs with NVL2 function

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not believe multiple delimiters like this are supported in Snowflake at this time.  Multiple byte and multiple character delimiters are supported, but they will need to be specified as the same delimiter repeated for either record or line.

Yes, it may be possible to do some post-processing or use Python scripts to achieve this. Or even SQL transformative statements. This is not really my area of expertise so if someone has an example for you, I'll let them add to the discussion.